# Mutate existing container for `rand` results in Julia?

Tags: random, julia, allocation, mutate

I have a simulation where the computation will reuse the random sample of a multi-dimensional random variable. I'd like to be able to re-use a pre-allocated container for better performance with less allocations.

Simplified example:

```
function f()
    container = zeros(2) # my actual use-case is an MvNormal
    map(1:100) do i
        container = rand(2)
        sum(container)
    end
end
```

I think the above is allocating a new vector as a result of `rand(2)` each time. I'd like to mutate `container` by storing the results of the `rand` call.

I tried the typical pattern of `rand!(container,...)` but there does not seem to be a built-in `rand!` function following the usual mutation convention in Julia.

How can I reuse the `container` or otherwise improve the performance of this approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

rand! exists in the `Random` module

```
julia> using Random

julia> a = zeros(2)
2-element Vector{Float64}:
 0.0
 0.0

julia> rand!(a);@show a;
a = [0.8139794738918935, 0.6336948436048475]
```